# Asking for reference to exclude firms belong to "NA", "UNCLS", “UQEQS”, “OTHEQ”, “SUSEQ” industries

Tags: reference-request, nonexpert

I am looking for academic papers suggesting that we should exclude firms in some industries which is : "NA" (Not Avaialble), Unclear (UNCLS), "OTHEQ" (Other equity), "SUSEQ" (Suspending equity) when doing reseach.